# Issue with collating data from four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables.

BHD
OPT
FTB
DRM

I would like to get the column agent and status from BHD, description from OPT, booking_actual retail from FTB, and analysis_master1 from DRM.

The column full_reference in BHD is linked to FTB.Reference, DRM.code linked to BHD.AGENT, and OPT_ID to BHD_ID.

I tried this:

```
 SELECT bad.agent as agents,
 bad.status as thestatus,
 desc.description as product,
 retail.booking_actual_retail as actualretail,
 country.analysis_master1 as countries
 from BHD bad
 inner join BHD bad on ftb.booking_reference = bad.FULL_REFERENCE
 inner join DRM Country on bad.agent = country.code
 inner join OPT desc on bad.id = desc.id
```

and got:

> The correlation name 'bad' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

Just wondering where I'm going wrong, or if someone has a better idea?

Comment: The first `INNER JOIN` is wrong. `from BHD bad
 inner join BHD bad on ftb.booking_reference = bad.FULL_REFERENCE` I think you meant `FTB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 SELECT bad.agent as agents,
 bad.status as thestatus,
 desc.description as product,
 retail.booking_actual_retail as actualretail,
 country.analysis_master1 as countries
 from BHD bad
 inner join FTB on ftb.booking_reference = bad.FULL_REFERENCE
 inner join DRM Country on bad.agent = country.code
 inner join OPT desc on bad.id = desc.id
```

Comment: I get a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'."

Comment: I changed the desc to desc1 and get:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'id'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "retail.booking_actual_retail" could not be bound.

Comment: Because `retail` table is not in from or join list. Is it one of your 4 tables in the query or an additional table?

Comment: I gotcha. I will mark yours right as that put me on the right path. Above I made one amendment, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bad.agent as Agents,
bad.status as TheStatus,
desc1.description as Product,
country.analysis_master1 as Country,
ftb.booking_actual_retail as ActualRetail,
ftb.Entered_Date
from BHD bad
inner join FTB on ftb.booking_reference = bad.FULL_REFERENCE
inner join DRM Country on bad.agent = country.code
inner join OPT desc1 on bad.BHD_ID = desc1.OPT_ID
```